# SQL server index creation vs enabling index

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, non-clustered-index

Have a table in sql server 2008 r2 with like 50 million records. Inserting into the table through SSIS is taking lot of time because i have five non clustered indexes on that table which I cannot remove. Thought of dropping and creating the index before and after the ssis package runs, but that also is taking a lot of time. Want to understand if disabling and enabling the index will give me a better performance.

Comment: what makes you think the indexes are causing the poor performance?

Comment: when i remove the index and load the data it is taking 1% of the time its taking to load with index

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at JNK's answer below
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19890/when-should-indexes-be-dropped-and-recreated

1. DISABLE non-clustered indexes, leaving clustered index intact
2. Perform load of raw into your data table
3. REBUILD NC indexes

Comment: Even disabling and rebuilding is not helping..do we have any other option?

Comment: Are you using an ORDER BY clause in your select? (Is the input sorted?) If YES, the try inserting unsorted
If NO then try inserting Sorted

Comment: I am trying to load data from a flat file and it is not sorted. I do not have control over the select queries running over the table. :(

Comment: Since you are loading from a flat file, have you tried loading data using BCP?

Comment: refer "Importing Data into a Table" here - https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/working-with-the-bcp-command-line-utility/